# Why does "yes&" crash my Bash session?

Tags: bash, background-process, job-control, jobs, yes

"Yes, and..." is a wonderful rule-of-thumb in improvisational comedy. Not so much in the UNIX world.

When I run the admittedly silly `yes&` command, I cannot interrupt it. The terminal crashes or gets stuck into a loop.

I expect the `yes` process to be suspended immediately, since any process in the background should suspend if attempting to write to stdout, but it doesn't seem to be the case, and I'm wondering why.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Background processes which write to the terminal are only suspended if the `TOSTOP` output mode is set, which isn’t the case by default. Try

```
stty tostop
yes &
```

and you’ll see that `yes` is suspended.

Background processes which *read* from the terminal are suspended by default, because there’s no sensible way for them to get correct input.

See [the section on accessing the terminal in the GNU C library manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Access-to-the-Terminal.html).

With `TOSTOP` off, the terminal doesn’t crash or become stuck, it remains responsive to input; so you can stop the background `yes` by either killing it (`kill %` if it’s the only background job), or bringing it to the foreground (`fg`) and stopping it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>). You’ll have to enter commands blindly but they will work.

Answer (score 5):

Stephen's answer is excellent, but I would add that you can regain control of your bash session by foregrounding the process, and then interrupting it:

```
$ yes &
y
y
y
y
...
```

Although you won't see it, enter:

`fg`<kbd>Enter</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>

`fg` is the job control command to move a backgrounded job back to the foreground, and of course, <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> sends a `SIGINT` signal to the current job.  In cases where you have multiple jobs backgrounded, `fg` can be followed by a `jobspec` argument to stipulate which job you want to move to the foreground.  Details are in the `bash` man page.

Comment: A simple `%` would also work instead of `fg` to foreground the last backgrounded job.

Comment: It seems my answer wasn’t excellent enough to read in its entirety ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, I must apologize, I did tune out after the first couple of paragraphs.  ;)